# What defines ragtime as a music genre/style?

Tags: genre, style

What makes a ragtime song a *ragtime song*? Which are the key and defining elements of ragtime? What differentiates it from other music from the era?

Comment: what do you think of Jacob's answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The defining characteristic of ragtime music is a specific type of syncopation in which melodic accents occur between metrical beats. This results in a melody that seems to be avoiding some metrical beats of the accompaniment by emphasizing notes that either anticipate or follow the beat ("a rhythmic base of metric affirmation, and a melody of metric denial" 
>   -Wikipedia

Basically, it's just a specific form of syncopation where accents do not fall on a beat.